# Why can't I inherit the prototype of the Animal class in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a new class `Dog` that inherits via prototypical inheritance from the `Animal` class:

```
function Animal() {
  this.name = "animal";
  this.writeName = function() {
    document.write(this.name);
  }    
}

function Dog() {
  this.name = "dog";
  this.prototype = new Animal();
}

new Dog().writeName()
```

​
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbrTF/1/)

However, I get a Javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Dog> has no method 'say'`.

Why? Shouldn't the `Dog` object retain an `Animal` object as a prototype?

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right code?  The word `say` doesn't appear there once.

Comment: Because there are no classes? ;) But the issue is that `this` is already the *wrong object* at that time (as well as the [[prototype]] being *too late* for `new` to utilize).

Comment: BTW, use console.log instead of document.write and alert. It will make your life so much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ryan's answer is correct, of course, but he doesn't really *say* what's different about it and it might not be clear to a beginner, so...

The mistake you're making is that `this.prototype = new Animal();` assigns an `Animal` instance to a property named `prototype` on the current `Dog` *instance* (referred to by `this`), but there's nothing special about a property named `prototype` in this context.

The `prototype` property is only magical on *function* objects. When you create a new instance of `SomeFunc` using `new SomeFunc()` that new object's internal/hidden *[[prototype]]* pointer will refer to the object pointed to by `SomeFunc.prototype`. The `prototype` name isn't special in any other context.

Answer (score 7):

```
function Animal() {
  this.name = "animal";
  this.writeName = function() {
    document.write(this.name);
  }    
}

function Dog() {
  this.name = "dog";

}
Dog.prototype = new Animal();
dog = new Dog();
dog.writeName();
```

now dog has all of the properties of animal.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbrTF/3/)

Answer (score 2):

The "prototype" property is just a regular property. The real [[Proto]] property that deals with delegation is hidden and can't be directly manipulated after an object is created (except with some extensions: in Firefox, its the `__proto__` property).

A correct Javascript inheritance example that is similar in spirit to what you are doing would use Object.create to create a dog with the correct [[Prototype]] property:

```
function Animal() {
  this.name = "animal";
  this.writeName = function() {
    document.write(this.name);
  }    
}

function Dog() {
  var dog = Object.create(new Animal())
  dog.name = "dog";
  return dog;
}

(new Dog()).writeName()
```

A more idiomatic example would be something like ryan's answer, although I would recommend using `Object.create` instead of `new Animal` to instantiate the dog prototype and I would put the animal methods in a separate animal prototype instead of manually attaching them in the constructor like you are doing.

Comment: @pst: I was talking about how he was expecting the "prototype" property to behave specially.

Comment: Okay, that's better, +1 :-) Is `Object.create(proto)` [natively] available in 3rd edition, though?

Comment: @pst: I can't remember now, but its very easy to write a polyfill for it when its not available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill

Comment: Someone recently added an answer to this so it showed up in my list, this is a strange way of using prototype and Object.create. Animal has instance member (namely this.name) you can "inherit" by calling `Animal.call(this,"dog");` in the Dog constructor. Animal has shared member (writeName) that should be declared as `Animal.prototye.writeName=function()` that can be inherited by Dog with `Dog.prototype=Object.create(Animal.prototype);` So as to not completely overwrite the Dog prototype every time you create a Dog instance. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @HMR: THe reason this looks weird is because I'm using the `new` keyword to call my constructors but I'm not taking advantage of the `.prototype` magic. This was to keep things closer to the original question but I'd guess it might be clearer to go all the way and rename the functions to `make_animal` and `make_dog` and invoke them without the `new` keyword, since this way its explicit that my code isn't actually using `this` anywhere.